# Bone IK Warping Mesh?

Tags: rigging, bones

I'm following this tutorial: [How to Create Realistic Trees](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gQUO9yL2vYQ)

When I set up the IK Bone and move it, the branch stretches and moves, but the end bends sharply:

[image: Bone Bend A]
[image: Bone Bend B]
[image: Bone Bend C]

The steps:

1. Select the tree with the Skin Modifier.
2. In the Skin Modifier Panel, click "Create Armature."
3. Select the Armature
4. Enter Edit Mode
5. Open Data Panel -> Display Group -> click "B-Bone" display.
6. Select the end bone.
7. Shift-D to duplicate the bone. Alt-F to switch direction.
8. Open Properties Panel. Scroll to Item -> Bone Name, rename it by putting an ".IK" at the end.
9. Select the (original) bone you made a copy of earlier (not the one with the IK in the name).
10. Enter Pose Mode
11. Bone Constraints Panel -> Add Bone Constraint -> Inverse Kinematics. Target: Armature | Bone: Find the one with the ".IK" at the end | Length: set to the number of segments to the tree base (e.g. 4)
12. Move the IK bone and watch the rest of the branch move.

Problem: Warping.

Any suggestions?

Comment: go to edit mode with Bone.065.IK selected and disable *Deform* in Properties panel in Bone tab. This bone is contributing to deformation and it shouldn't, it should only drive the IK chain.

Comment: Perfect, thanks!

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dq4LF.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kj2iJ.png